# Spring Boot - java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized

Tags: spring-boot

Just created a quick and simple 'sandbox' application to test out Spring-boot.

I'm getting the following error when attempting to run it -regardless of the versioning (tried to drop down to 1.4.7.RELEASE as well).

Also, almost all of the answers I've read on other posts seems to indicate that there's a mismatch in the versions somewhere -but how is that possible in this case?  I was attempting to use the parent to avoid versioning conflicts to begin with.

**POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sandbox.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootSandbox</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootSandbox</name>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**ApplicationRunner**

```
@SpringBootApplication//(scanBasePackages = "com.sandbox")
@ComponentScan("com.sandbox")
public class ApplicationRunner extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ApplicationRunner.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRunner.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
2017-10-20 10:48:42.483  WARN 8828 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Around
2017-10-20 10:48:42.485 ERROR 8828 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2805c96b: startup date [Fri Oct 20 10:48:42 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) [spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:556) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at com.sandbox.configuration.ApplicationRunner.main(ApplicationRunner.java:31) [classes/:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around... and checking other Spring boot setups, I adjusted my ApplicationRunner as follows, and it seems to run without error now.  I'm still looking into what the difference is between these approaches and why this one works.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.sandbox")
public class BootApplicationRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication.run(BootApplicationRunner.class, args);
    }

    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

    }
}
```